# German National Visa

Tags: germany

The national employment visa has "§ 2 ABS 1 BESCHV (BLAUE KARTE EU) AUFENTHALTSDAUER ENTSPRICHT GULTIGKEIT" in the remarks. Can someone help understand what this means?

Comment: *Wegener* does not seem to be a German word (although it seems to be a relatively common name).  Are you certain that you have transcribed it correctly?

Comment: It was in the next line with some indent I assumed it to be a part of that sentence.

Comment: I suspect that it is the name of the officer who issued the visa. If I recall correctly this is common on German visas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says tha according to §2 part 1 of [Beschäftigungsverordnung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Besch%C3%A4ftigungsverordnung) (Blue Card EU) you can stay in Germany as long as your visa is valid. (As opposite to visitor's visa which often have a shorter period of stay than validity period).